# Javascript becomes unresponsive after button presses

Tags: javascript, html

When I push the buttons (N and O ) maybe 10 times, the script becomes very unresponsive, does anyone have a solution for this? 
What I'm trying to do is to have 2 menus in a game. This is a test which should have the same effect.

```html
//html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Snake</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
        canvas{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid "Black";
            margin: auto;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        </style>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "menu2.js"></script>     
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "menu1.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            main();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
    //main function
    var
    COLS = 20,
    ROWS = 20,
    canvas,
    ctx,
    keystate,
    KEY_O = 79,
    KEY_N = 78;
    var main = function()
    {
        // create and initiate the canvas element
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = COLS*20;
        canvas.height = ROWS*20;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // add the canvas element to the body of the document
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        // sets an base font for bigger score display
        ctx.font = "12px Ariel";
        keystate = {};
        // keeps track of the keybourd input
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
            keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
            delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
        });
        menu1();
    };

    //first menu
    var menu1 = function()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.height, canvas.width);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (keystate[KEY_N]) {
            menu2();
        }});
    };

    //second menu
    var menu2 = function()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.height, canvas.width);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (keystate[KEY_O]) {

            menu1();
        }});
    };
```

Comment: You keep on adding EventListeners - you should only need to do so once

Comment: You add an additional listener each time the function is called.

Comment: `menu1` adds an event listener that calls `menu2`. `menu2` adds an event listener that calls `menu1`. This ___exponentially___ increases the amount of click event handlers being called.

Comment: If I remove document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {}) in menu1 and menu2 the buttons won't work. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `menu2();` or `menu1();` you are adding a new `EventListener`, which again calls `menu2();` or `menu1();` ...and more event listeners get added every time. This means that your number of event listeners grows at an enormous rate as you keep pressing keys, and slows the script down. You only need one `EventListener` per key, set it outside of the menu function.

Answer (score 0):

issue is with adding `eventListeners` on each call of `menu1` and `menu2` .what you need is simply put it out side of both in main like this:

```
 document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (keystate[KEY_N]) {
            menu2();
        }
            if (keystate[KEY_O]) {
                menu1();
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Snake</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
        canvas{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid "Black";
            margin: auto;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        </style>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
    
    var
    COLS = 20,
    ROWS = 20,
    canvas,
    ctx,
    keystate,
    KEY_O = 79,
    KEY_N = 78;
    var main = function()
    {
        // create and initiate the canvas element
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = COLS*20;
        canvas.height = ROWS*20;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // add the canvas element to the body of the document
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        // sets an base font for bigger score display
        ctx.font = "12px Ariel";
        keystate = {};
        // keeps track of the keybourd input
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
            keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
            if (keystate[KEY_N]) {
                menu2();
            }
           
                if (keystate[KEY_O]) {

                    menu1();
                }
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
            delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
        });
        menu1();
    };

    //first menu
    var menu1 = function()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "Red";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.height, canvas.width);
       
    };

    //second menu
    var menu2 = function()
    {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "Blue";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.height, canvas.width);
       
    };
    main();

    </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** open snippet window then click inside it then press `o` and `n` to see the effect.